# Time complexity of Powerset in Python

Tags: python, time-complexity, powerset

The time complexity of this code to create a powerset from distinct integers is listed as `O(n * 2^n)` at all places including the Leetcode solution.

I listed the complexity of each step as a code comment and for me the overall complexity is coming out as `O(n^2 * 2^n)`. You can see we are looping over `n` times on a line of code whose own complexity is `O(n * 2^n)`, thus, shouldn't  be the time complexity of this solution be `O(n^2 * 2^n)`?

```py
class Solution:
    def subsets(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        n = len(nums)
        output = [[]]
        
        for num in nums: # O(n)
            output += [curr + [num] for curr in output] # n for adding two lists and then 2^n times so O(n * 2^n)
        
        return output
```

Comment: @ShadowRanger There is no `n_0` and `c` such that for all `n > n_0`, `n * 2^n < c * 2^n`. Informally, you can discard lower order *terms* but not lower order *factors*.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Big O is a mathematical concept with a formal definition; it does not depend on what is "relevant" to a programmer, and in fact is not even specifically used only in computer science. Whether or not the difference between `O(2^n)` and `O(n^2 * 2^n)` is relevant for a given purpose, they *are* different - unlike, say, `O(2^n)` and `O(n^2 + 2^n)`, which are the same.

Comment: @KellyBundy: That's a better analogy I accept. I'm burninating my comments; in practice, I *do* treat exponential as making the polynomial term irrelevant, and I can't think of any scenario where the additional `n *` factor will *ever* matter, but yeah, formally, it can't be *dropped*. (I'd leave the comments, but I think this is distracting from the OP's problem, not helping)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code can be rewritten as follows:

```
class Solution:
    def subsets(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        n = len(nums)
        output = [[]]
        
        for k, num in enumerate(nums):
            new_items = [curr + [num] for curr in output] # O(2^k * (k+1))
            output += new_items # O(2^k)
            
        return output
```

The time complexity of the k-th iteration of the loop is `O(2^k * (k+1) + 2^k) = O(2^k * (k+2))`. To get the complexity of the whole loop, we need to take the sum of the the expressions `2^k * (k+2)` from `k=0` to `k=n-1`, This sum [is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+2%5Ek*%28k%2B2%29%2C+k%3D0%2C+n-1) `2^n * n`.

Comment: I don't see you accounting for all the *deletions* of the temporary `new_items` lists, but that only adds O(n), so doesn't matter.

Comment: @KellyBundy There are also other O(n) contributions: retrieval of `num` from the lists `nums`,  creation of the temporary list assigned to `new_items`, assignment of this list to `new_items`. But, as you wrote, this does not matter.